# Импортировать цены на бензин в google таблицу

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Необходимо подгружать в google таблицу цены на бензин в режиме онлайн. В интернете не удалось найти готовых решений,например таких как загрузка курса доллара с сайта ЦБ.

Нашел вот этот сайт https://multigo.ru/benzin/info-benzin-price/avprice, который предоставляет виджет с ценами для встройки на сайт. Возможно как то вытащить цены, например с помощью importxml?

ссылка на виджет:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" 
src="https://multigo.ru/informer/avprices1/c/lat=55.755814&lng=37.617635" 
frameborder="0" width="140px" height="150px" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На том сайте, который указали вы, для того чтобы видеть актуальные цены - нужно логиниться.
Для примера, я нашел другой сайт с ценами на бензин https://www.benzin-price.ru/price.php?region_id=77&brand_id=687 .
Чтобы вытащить в таблицу цену бензина А-92 по АЗС Asco, подойдёт такая формула:

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.benzin-price.ru/price.php?region_id=77&brand_id=687";"//td[@class='price'][3]")`

Comment: Благодарю! Это то, что нужно!